# What did I do wrong to get $i = 1$ from $\frac{1}{i} = -\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-1}}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

$$\dfrac{1}{i} = -\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{-1}}$$

Applying the formula $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = x$:

$$-\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{-1}} = - (-1) = 1 \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad i = 1$$

What did I do wrong?

Comment: One minute: $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = x$ is wrong. It should be $\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}$

Comment: The formula $\frac x{\sqrt x} = x$ is not correct.  Nor is the formula $\frac x{\sqrt x} = \sqrt x$.  ($\sqrt x$ is just not well (uniquely) defined).

Comment: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}$ would presumably be $\sqrt{x}$ if anything. So you would get $\frac{1}{i}=-\sqrt{-1}$ which is actually reasonable since $\frac{1}{i}=-i$. However there are some similar manipulations that you can apparently do that are not reasonable because $-1$ has two square roots: $i$ and $-i$.

Comment: Does $$\frac{4}{\sqrt{4}}=4?$$

Comment: Actually, I guess $\frac x{\sqrt x} = \sqrt x \iff x = (\sqrt x)^2$ which is by definition true so we get $-\frac {-1}{\sqrt -1} = -\sqrt{-1} = -i$ and it *is* true that $\frac 1i = -i$.  But you need to be careful about $\sqrt{}$ as it's never *clear*ly defined as a *single* value and the *definition* of $i$ as "$\sqrt{-1}$" is one fraught with thorns that make all mathematicians cringe.

Comment: Thanks to all. My silly mistake.

Comment: One manipulation that is allowed for non-zero complex $z = (x + iy)$ is to define $\overline{z}$ [i.e. the *conjugate* of $z$] as $(x - iy)$.  Then, define $|z|$ [i.e. the *norm* of $z$] as $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  This implies that $$z \times \overline{z} = |z|^2.$$ Then, you have that for all non-zero complex $(z)$, $$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{\overline{z}}{z \times \overline{z}} = \frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}.$$

Comment: It can never be stated enough that $i$ is defined so that $i^2 = -1$ but that needs not mean that $i = \sqrt{-1}$.   Just as $(-2)^2 = 4$ does *not* mean $-2 = \sqrt 4$.  For any $w \ne 0$ there will be *two* values $r_1$ and $r_2$ so that $r_1^2 = w$ and $r_2^2 = w$ (and it turns out that $r_1 = -r_2$) and we don't have any non-arbitrary way to declare *one* and not the other as *the* square root.  So we really *SHOULDN'T* ever say $i = \sqrt{-1}$ as $(-i)^2 = -1$ as well.  It's not *wrong* but assuming it is consistant is fraught with thorns and *will* sting you eventually.

Comment: Per the comment of @fleablood in Real Analysis, there is the convention that the square root of a positive number will unambiguously refer to the positive square root.  In Complex Analysis, if (non-zero) $z = re^{i\theta} ~: r > 0, -\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, then there are two complex numbers $w$ such that $w^2 = z$.  These are $w_1 = \sqrt{r} \times e^{i\theta/2}$ and $w_2 = \sqrt{r} \times e^{i(\pi + \theta/2)}.$  ...see next comment

Comment: Although at least one author (e.g. Bruce Palka) adopted the convention that the *principal* $\sqrt{z}$ denotes $w_1$ rather than $w_2$ if and only if $-\pi/2 < \theta/2 \leq \pi/2$ [within a modulus of $(2\pi)$], it is unclear (at least to me) how widespread this convention is.

Comment: @fleablood if $\sqrt{~}$ is being defined such that it returns only the principal square root, then $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is a perfectly correct statement (*although still not a good starting point*), just as saying $2=\sqrt{4}$ is a perfectly correct statement.  (*The starting point in this context being something along the lines of working with $\Bbb R^2$ imbued with a special addition and multiplication and referring to what was created as the complex numbers*)

Comment: @JMoravitz Doesn't that depend on whether, in Complex Analysis, the convention of *principal* square root has been well defined and then adopted?

Comment: @user2661923 Of course, expressions only have meaning if the notation has been defined.  That is true of all things.  The point being that although in some contexts it is difficult to distinguish between $+i$ and $-i$... they are perfectly unambiguously able to be distinguished if following certain methods of defining things, $+i$ corresponding to the element $(0,1)$ of $\Bbb R^2$ which was imbued with the operations I alluded to earlier while $-i$ corresponds to the element $(0,-1)$ with no confusion.

Comment: The problem is whatever conventions we adopt we will have issue as to when and if $\sqrt a\sqrt b = \sqrt{ab}$ or $-\sqrt{ab}$ and whatever convention we use we will not work such questions out consistently.  Frankly coming up with a definition for the *principal* square root isn't really worth the issue.   And worrying about what is *the* value the square root does usually sting us.  Who *cares* whether $\sqrt{-3 - 4i}$ is $-1+2i$ or if it is $1-2i$?  Declaring it must be one or the other to serve one purpose *will* eventually lead to a special case exception.

Comment: @fleablood I disagree.  Palka's approach seems sensible to me: for non-zero complex $z$ you have that arg$\left[\sqrt{z} ~\right]$ will always lie in the range $(-\pi/2, \pi/2],~$ within a modulus of $(2\pi)$.  This permits $\sqrt{z}$ to have an unambiguous reference and promotes syntactic sugar, in the same way that using $e^{i\theta}$ to designate $[\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)]$ promotes syntactic sugar.  The syntactic sugar promotes expressing/attacking/solving Complex Analysis problems.

Comment: Yeah, but what *good* does it do?  You still have the $\sqrt{ab} \ne \sqrt a \sqrt b$ issue.  I don't particularly care if we declare $\arg[\sqrt z] \in (-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2]$ or if $\arg[\sqrt z] \in [0,\pi)$ so long as we are aware that $w^2 = z$ will have *two* solutions and we can not assume any naive errors of $w^2 = z\implies w=\sqrt z$ in any of its forms, subtle of overt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = x$ is wrong, it should be: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}$ as you said. Completing the rest of the problem with this statement, we see that RHS = $\frac{1}{\sqrt{-1}} = -(\frac{-1}{\sqrt{-1}}) -i$ and $\frac{1}{i} = -i$ as well. So, LHS = RHS.

Comment: This is not sufficiently different than the other already existing answer(s) and so was unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = x$$
is wrong, it should be:
$$\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x}} = \sqrt{x}$$

Comment: @Iamaperson Answering your own question after leading comments and hints help you understand and resolve the issue is highly *encouraged*.  The OP is doing the right thing here.  You make it sound as though this shouldn't have happened.  That is not the case.